# Why is the progression V - IV not in my harmony and voice leading book?

Tags: voice-leading

It is basically saying that dominant must go to tonic or to the vi chord in a deceptive resolution but what about V - IV? This is a common chord progression too right? So why is it not in my voice leading book?

Comment: As suggested previously - speak with ABRSM. They're amenable, and should give valid reasons.

Comment: If your books is from the ABRSM, are you specifically prepping for some ABRSM purpose?

Comment: If the textbook is old-school, and many are, the progressions used by Bach and his contemporaries form the basis of the many rules proposed.  V-IV is very uncommon in this era.

Comment: I am learning from several books. One is ABRSM but this particular one is Harmony and Voice Leading 5th edition.

Comment: We might think this comes from studying common-practice harmony, however it is actually a problem with non-theoretical theory text books, and even more so with monist models of music theory. If this problem were the result of having too narrow a view of the common practice then how would we explain real theory books which do contain this progression? Riemann for instance does theorize the so called V to IV which for him would be termed dominant to subdominant (in the minor mode).

Answer (score 7):

> ...It is basically saying that dominant must go to tonic or to the vi chord in a deceptive resolution

That's just basic *functional* harmony: pre-dominant to dominant to tonic.

Depends on how the book defines "deceptive" cadence or progression, but the dominant moving to *any* chord not the tonic in a cadence is by some definitions a deceptive cadence.

The book may have an example of a passing `IV` chord, like `V IV V`. From the functional perspective that would not really be a *progression* but a *prolongation* of a `V` chord.

When the functional flow of pre-dominant to dominant to tonic is backwards - like `V IV` it can be called a *retrogression* instead of a progression.

> ...This [`V IV`] is a common chord progression too right?

Bars 9-11 of a typical 12 bar blues will go `|V|IV|I|` that's pretty common.

Lot's of people get bent out of shape that functional harmony would label that a retrogression, some kind of "wrong" progression. But they also fail to point out that the *completion* and repetition of the 12 bar form (bars 9-12 and back to bar 1) is very commonly `|V|IV|I|V:|:I` which *conforms* to functional harmonic progression.

If your textbook really does not show an example of `V IV` - even an example to show that while rare in common practice music it can be found if you look long and hard enough - it's probably just a matter of the book presenting the most common, idealized style of classical harmony.

Piston's *Harmony* covers the `V IV` progression in two places: one is about avoiding the *cross relationship of the tritone*, and the other is the *irregular resolution of `V7`*. In a nutshell, to avoid the cross relationship, when the progression is root position `V IV` don't put the leading tone of `V` in the soprano. And regarding irregular resolution Piston says: "more often the subdominant is found in first inversion." He then gives Mozart K. 279 as an example (no measure number given) in `F: | ii6 I6/4 V7 | IV6 V6/5 I |`. The seventh of `V7` can be a held, common tone when it becomes the root of `IV`.

Comment: "it's probably just a matter of the book presenting the most common, idealized style of harmony." Just noting there should probably be a qualifier here: the most common, idealized style of "CLASSICAL" harmony.  V-IV progressions are all over pop and jazz in a lot of contexts.  They're perfectly normal.  They just tend to be "outlawed" in textbooks trying to teach classical or pseudo-classical styles and norms.

Comment: Thanks, V7 to IV6 is covered but then again isnt IV6 more related to vi than to IV?

Comment: @armani, of course the bass is the same for `IV6` and `vi`, and functionally both a pre-dominant, so there is a similarity. I think the subtle difference is `vi` will provide that minor, modal region of the key that `IV6` does not. I think it's good to develop a sensitivity to that difference. It's a personal choice of "color" which to use.

Comment: @Athanasius and indeed the progression was not entirely unknown in the period, for example at the end of _Praise the Lord with Harp and Tongue_ from Handel's _Solomon._

Answer (score 1):

The "classical" problem with this sequence occurs when the chords are in root position. It's difficult to move chords in parallel without producing parallel fifths or octaves. The sequence V-IV does occur with both chords in first inversion; V7-IV6; there are no parallel fifths or octaves.

Comment: Those two chords in particular or any two chords a step apart?

Comment: Any two chords a step apart can be connected in 63 positions (complete chords, no parallel problems.)  As mentioned in other answers, the V-IV sounds "backward" from the usual IV-V but is fine if the voice-leading is good.

Comment: In fact, it seems like V-IV might even have better voice leading since the leading tone B in the G chord can move up to a C as long as another voice completes the chord. That's basically what you brought up in V7-IV6, although note that your V7 is not in first inversion (for that, should be V65, no?). Good perspective on the question.

Comment: The two chords in root position do pose a problem, but it is not insoluble; see, for example, the end of _Praise the Lord with Harp and Tongue_ from Handel's _Solomon._

Answer (score 0):

Your textbook is telling you how to write 'safe' harmonies in the particular style required for elementary theory examinations.

You have noticed that there are other styles.   Good!

Comment: In fact, however, the sequence IV-V may occur even in common practice styles.